# Work-arounds for the lack of version control branching support in Enterprise Architect

Tags: enterprise-architect

From the user guide

*Currently, Enterprise Architect does not support Version Control Branching.
Work-arounds to achieve similar results might be possible for certain version-control products; contact Sparx Support for advice.*

The support channel available to me has not been very responsive so let's see what SO has to say about it. Basically I want to manage my model the same way I manage the product it's modelling so when my product repository is branched I want the model to branch with it. What are the different ways to deal with this? Pros/cons?

Comment: As Sparx support suggests "for certain VCs" we'd need to know which one you're using.

Comment: I'm using SVN but if another VC or a database makes things easier I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: a model is not code. The difficulty with a model (in XMI format) is that it looks like being readable but in fact it isn't. So the problem comes with merging. While a merge in code will create obvious results (compiler errors due to bad merges can be corrected more or less easily) a wrong merge for a model simply creates rubbish. For that reason you can not branch and merge a model.

Now, how can you go about this? As said: there is no easy solution. One way is to create separate repositories for each branch. As long as the branches live independent you're fine. But how can you merge changes from one branch to the other? Sad to say, but the only way I can recommend it the manual one. There is actually no usable compare tool for UML models. You need to locate the changes per package and export that package.

- If (and it's impossible to explain in a few sentences) the changes are just local to that package you can import the changes via a simple XMI import.
- If you are able to locate changes to single elements you can create a dummy package, move those elements temporarily into that package and move it over. That will update the elements in the other branch but also move them from their original position (as you did in the first branch) and you need to move the elements back to where they were in both branches and get rid of the dummy package.
- In case of structural changes you're probably better off doing the change manually in the other branch and have an eye review.

To sum up: model branches are nothing you like to work with. Look for alternative ways. The best is likely to have everything in one model and find ways to mark the branches inside the model using packages structures, tagged values or whatever. Not easy to handle either.

Comment: The branches I'm looking for are not primarily feature branches that will merge back at some point. Instead they represent variants that may need maintenance separate from the mainline and occasionally you may want to take a new feature on the mainline and move it to the branch. I think you confirmed what I suspected that this is no easy thing but you also gave me a number of new ways which I didn't think about.

Comment: Yes. This is often underestimated. I'm sure it will keep your and your colleagues brains busy for a while ;-)